# Firebase Polymer PWA with custom domain, signInWithPopup doesn't work on mobile device

Tags: redirect, firebase, oauth, polymer, progressive-web-apps

Testing on desktop works fine, the various provider's popups come up. On mobile device however with each provider a new browser window opens, but the address is the non-customized hosting URL of the firebase app and the sign-in flow halts.

Originally the Firebase documentation advises the non custom hosting URL to be used in the redirect URLs. I changed those for all providers to the custom one: `https://valleydevfest.com/__/auth/handler` instead of `https://valleydevfest-620d6.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler` (for both Facebook app, Twitter app and my Github app too). That didn't help at all and the mobile Chrome still redirects to some `https://valleydevfest-620d6.firebaseapp.com/...` address, which either halts loading or it loads a very broken version of the website (instead of the OAuth login).

Most relevant code:

```
var signIn = function(providerId) {
  var provider = getProviderForProviderId(providerId);
  var that = this;
  return this.auth.signInWithPopup(provider).catch(function(error) {
...
```

https://github.com/gdgfresno/valleydevfest/blob/develop/scripts/helper/firebase.js#L43

How can I overcome that?

(Whole source of the app: https://github.com/gdgfresno/valleydevfest/tree/develop)

Comment: Just gave it a try on https://valleydevfest.com with Chrome for Android and it seemed fine. Did you figure out what the issue was?

Comment: Still doesn't work for me and I can still reproduce it, but it worked for most of the attendees. I'm using Chrome on Android

Comment: Can it matter that my default browser is not Chrome but Dolhin? It's a Samsung Note 3 phone BTW with KitKat.

Comment: I think it doesn't matter that I have two factor auth enabled, it goes sideways with the first redirection. Desktop works fine.

Comment: I implemented anonymous login for now so this question won't be relevant for a while.

Comment: It might be a kitkat issue. I just tried with Dolphin on a Nougat without issue.

Comment: Might be. Actually I was wrong and I have 5.0 lollipop (android wear  tutorials required 5.1 lollipop). I'll debug this. Since then i enabled firebase anonymous login so the whole issue is not as serious now. My phone is old, 3+ years, I will get a new one